# BBQ history plugin - get previous hash

Tags: jquery, hash, history

I am using BBQ history plugin in this code:

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {

    var url = $.param.fragment();           
    var new_page = url.replace('.php', '');

    if (new_page == 'product') {
        var new_page_num = 1;
    } else if (new_page == 'installations') {
        var new_page_num = 2;
    } else if (new_page == 'blog') {
        var new_page_num = 3;
    } else if (new_page == 'contact') {
        var new_page_num = 4;
    }

    if (new_page_num == cur_page_num) {
        return false;
    } else if (new_page_num > cur_page_num) {
        nextPage();
    } else if (new_page_num < cur_page_num) {
        previousPage();
    }

    // Remove class 'current'
    $('a.current').removeClass( 'current' );

    // Add .current class to "current" nav link(s), only if url isn't empty.
    url && $( 'a[href="#' + url + '"]' ).addClass( 'current' );

});

$(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
```

On 'hashchange' event I want to perform this action:

Compare the current url (cur_page_num) to the next url (new_page_num) and execute
either the nextPage() or previousPage() function.

I can get the next url (var new_page).

Does anyone knows how I can get the hash that I came from?

(localhost/#hash1 to localhost/#hash2:
hash1 < hash2 so execute nextPage();, how can I get hash1?)

Thanks!!